# “SQL command” vs “Table or view” when importing entire tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

When using an OLEDB source editor, is there a performance benefit or difference in using "Sql Command" over "Table or View" when you want the *entire* table?

This is a variation on [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176930/ssis-ole-db-source-editor-data-access-mode-sql-command-vs-table-or-view/176933), in which the asker is talking about scenarios where they only want *one* or *some* columns in a table - in which case there is a benefit to using "Sql Command", as a `select * from` is still executed in the background when using "Table or View" even when columns are unticked.

I've also found [this entry on the MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlperf/2007/04/29/set-up-ole-db-source-to-read-from-view-efficiently/) which states it is more efficient when looking at **views** due to the use of `OpenRowset` and a `SET ROWCOUNT 1` which results in an inefficient query plan being cached and reused for the actual execution.

But if you're loading in a **table** and want **every column**, is there still an advantage to using the "Sql Command" option over "Table or View"?

Answer (score 1):

At one point in the product's past, selecting the table name from the drop down versus writing an explicit `SELECT * FROM MyTable` resulted in one fewer operation being performed. The table name selection did...something I can't reproduce now. It'd issue a command like though that resulted in a SELECT * but with an outer wrapper around it.

Profiler reports for 2014, it issued the command `select * from [SB].[EventLog]` A 2005/2008 instance would have indicated it did something like `sp_somethingweird [SB].[EventLog]`